# .htaccess rewrite URL with additional question mark “?”

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

With .htaccess i can't get working such link:

```
/quiz/results/solution-one/?email=myemail@domain.com
```

into

```
/results.php?level=4&email=myemail@domain.com
```

(solution-one should turn into level=4)

I have spend a few hours building .htaccess code:

```
Rewriterule  ^quiz\/results\/solution-one/(.*)/?$ /var/www/domain.com/public_html/results.php?level=4$1 [QSA,L]
```

Or this one:

```
Rewriterule  ^quiz\/results\/solution-one/([=@.a-zA-Z-]*) /var/www/domain.com/public_html/results.php?level=4&$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think your existing rule would match the URL?

Comment: My nearest match was this one: Rewriterule  ^quiz\/results\/solution-one/([=@.a-zA-Z-]*) /var/www/domain.com/public_html/results.php?level=4&$1 [QSA,L] , but it doesnt work if i add "question mask" before email.

Comment: That is what the "What is matched?" section implies.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule  ^quiz/results/solution-one/?$ results.php?level=4 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Without file path, but relative to root. And without test for query string (not part of Rewriterule test uri)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it doesn't work. It get's only [level] => 4 and misses email.

Comment: Are you sure of that ? Because with `[QSA]`, it should be automatically added.

Comment: No other .htaccess rules ?

Comment: There is a lot of other .htaccess code. I will try to clean a bit and i will copy here.